# How you run thinkcmf framework backend locally with vue front end project

Tags: vue.js, https, thinkphp

I am trying to run thinkcmf framework backend with vue front end.
I get the bellow error.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://domainname.com:80/api/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

can anyone help with this?